# SQL for proportional overlap in PostGIS returns successful; no affected rows

Tags: postgis, sql, intersection

I have two tables one with block group+data and another with geometries of communities. I want to calculate the intersection area so I can later calculate the proportion of each block group in a given community

I wrote this query, which runs successfully but says no rows are affected--they should be. Basically, some block groups fall entirely into a community, and others are bisected by the community boundaries.
What is causing this?

```
SELECT
  ST_Intersection(bg_pop.geom, com.geom) as new_geom,
  ST_Area(ST_Intersection(bg_pop.geom, com.geom)) as new_area
FROM
  laco_pop_by_bg as bg_pop, laco_community as com
WHERE
 ST_Intersects(bg_pop.geom, com.geom)
```

Comment: Can you confirm they are both in the same CRS?

Comment: Yes, they are both in the same CRS

Comment: Even if datasets are in the same SRID, one might have been shifted for mysterious reason. It's always important to have a visual look at the data.